# angular: Translate elements of an object array in a template with ngx-translate

Tags: arrays, angular, ngx-translate

I have been searching for hours how I can translate the values of an object array with the module ngx-translate,
Here is an extract of my code but I don’t know how to implement the json file

Template HTML :

```
 <div class="sort-header-container">
    <table matSort class="mat-sort">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items" class="row">
        <td class="row">{{item.critere}}</td>
        <td>{{item.res}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

The object array in the service :

```
items: any[] = [
    { critere: "Code-modèle", res: "Mizuno Shadow 4" },
    { critere: "Code Libellé", res: "KR32" },
    { critere: "Stock", res: 10 },
    { critere: "Prix TTC", res: "Bleu" },
    { critere: "Couleur", res: 42 },
    { critere: "Matière", res: 125 },
    { critere: "Zone", res: 100 },
  ];
```

I need to translate only the critere column

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TranslatePipe` from `ngx-translate`.

```html
<div class="sort-header-container">
    <table matSort class="mat-sort">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items" class="row">
        <td class="row">{{item.critere | translate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.res}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Make sure your `critere` field have the corresponding translations in the json translation files

example for en english translation:

```json
{
  "Prix TTC": "Price",
  "Couleur": "Color",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As taken from the [example](https://github.com/ngx-translate/example/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts) in ngx-translate github

You can use the translate pipe in your code, like this:

```html
 <td class="row">{{ item.critere | translate }}</td>
```

For this to work, your `critere` would need to be keys in your language file, for example:

```json
{
  'Stock': 'Stock english translation',
  'Couleur': 'Is this color?'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers
Finally here's what I did :

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item_translate of ('PRODUCT.PRODUCT' | translate); let i = index " class="row"
        [ngStyle]="item_translate.critere == 'Stock' && stock<0 ?{color:'red'}:{color:'#474646'}">
        <td class="row">{{item_translate.critere}}</td>
        <td>{{items[i].res}}</td>
      </tr>
```

In my json example fr :

```
"PRODUCT": {
    "PRODUCT": [
      {
        "critere": "Code-modèle"
      },
      {
        "critere": "Code Libellé"
      },
      {
        "critere": "Stock"
      },
      {
        "critere": "Prix TTC"
      },
      {
        "critere": "Couleur"
      },
      {
        "critere": "Matière"
      },
      {
        "critere": "Zone"
      }
    ]
  }
```